# How to trigger session deletion automatically after it expires?

Tags: python, django

I need to delete expired sessions from database.

Similar Stack Overflow threads seem to suggest introducing a scheduled task (cron, Celery etc.) to run a check on expired sessions and delete them.

However, I want to avoid introducing heavy stack for such simple task and am looking for a "native" way to delete a session from a database AS SOON AS it expires.

So I have a `pre_delete` signal set on `Session` model that triggers the deletion if model's instance is expired. But there is one step remaining: I need Django to run `delete` on the instance as soon as it expires.

Ideally, I would need a method like

`request.session.on_expiry(some_function_that_deletes_a_session_from_db)`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: A session that expires is not an *event*. Django simply stores that datetime in the database (as `expire_date`), and hence it will never trigger something. The server can be idle for days. That is why a scheduled task is usually a good way, especially since it removes session data in "bulk" and is thus more efficient.

Comment: Plus, a cron is not a "heavy stack". Your system already supports cron jobs; all you need to do is configure it to fire the clearsessions task on a regular basis.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem: Thanks. My use case is that I also create folders in media root under current session name where some audio files are stored. So the rationale behind deleting the session instantly is to prevent those folders that are no longer necessary to take space on the server.

Comment: @barciewicz: the problem with such triggers is that if we create such triggers, and later restart the server, usually the "registered functions" will be removed, and thus that system will fail. Furthermore using signals is usually not a good idea (it should be used as a last resort), since many ORM calls can easily bypass the signals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I have a `pre_delete` signal set on `Session` model that triggers the deletion if model's instance is expired. But there is one step remaining: I need Django to run delete on the instance as soon as it expires.

I am not really following what difference this makes. If the `pre_delete` signal is fired, it means Django will delete the `Session` object, so deleting that in the `pre_delete` signal can only result in an error if I understand it. Furthermore signals are useful, but there are several ways to "bypass" signals through ORM calls. So signals should usually only be used if all else fails.

When cleaning up expired sessions, the removals are done in bulk, and usually it will *not* run the query. Therefore it might be better to just write a management command that frequently checks what data belongs to a session that no longer exists.

> Ideally, I would need a method like
>
> ```
> request.session.on_expiry(some_function_that_deletes_a_session_from_db).
> ```

The Django framework does not "actively" look to the expiration of a session, it simply checks if the session is expired when it needs that session. There are no triggers on expiring.

You could implement such triggers yourself, for example by each time when a session is created/updated, add some sort of asynchronic function that will run when the expiration date is reached. But that would result in a lot of bookkeeping, and furthermore, if the server is restarted and you did not implement these functions in a persistent manner, these triggers will not exist anymore.

In fact you do not need to introduce a heavy stack at all, it is *already* there. Indeed: Django has a [**`request.session.clear_expired`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.clear_expired) function that you can call to clear expired sessions. Furthermore it has constructed a `clearsessions` method that is a managmenet command, so if you enabled the `django.contrib.sessions` app, then there is a [management command named **`clearsessions`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#clearsessions) you can run with:

```
manage.py clearsessions
```

It is furthermore usually better to remove sessions in bulk than to delete these individually one at a time, since the load on the database will be lower. You can run this command often if you want to reduce the number of expired sessions.

You can easily [*write a custom management command* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/). This is more robust, since if a server restarts, it can still actively look for such files, it is also easy to configure how often it will run, and furthermore by doing this in bulk it might be more efficient.